# jQuery to select sibling

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I'm having trouble selecting the input value from this html:

```
<li class="t-item">
  <div class="t-mid">
    <span class="t-in t-state-selected">102/NAH</span>
    <input class="t-input" name="itemValue" value="subject:4033" type="hidden">
  </div>
</li>
```

I can get the value of the `<span>` element using the following:

```
var text = $("#TreeView .t-state-selected").text();
```

How do I get the value of the sibling `<input>` element?

Here's the complete function, if it helps give some context (the event is a Telerik TreeView OnLoad event):

```
    function OnLoad(e) {
        // _lastSubject is known, find the selected node and get the detail
        var treeView = $('#TreeView').data('tTreeView');
        var text = $("#TreeView .t-state-selected").text();
        console.log("ugh, what I really want is the sibling input value"); 
    }
```

Comment: I tried next(), of course.  By going through the process of writing the question out, my example is now working.  I suppose that's the value in writing the question on SO.  @JaredPar below also answers a question I had, which is, "Can I include "input" in the selection in case the elements shift slightly in a future release.

Comment: i'd use siblings instead of next, it's a little more flexible to you changing the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
var i $('#TreeView .t-state-selected').next('input');
```

This solution is a bit more robust because it will guarantee it gets an `input` element vs simply the next element of any type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method, which can be given a filter:

```
var $input = $("#TreeView .t-state-selected").siblings('.t-input');
```

This will work even if other elements appear later between the span and the input (while `next()` won't).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eMF7W/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
var $input = $("#TreeView .t-state-selected").next();
var inputVal = $input.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery function [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will do this.

```
var i = $("#TreeView .t-state-selected").next();
```